# dynamic show and hide of radio buttons based on output of another radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working with the following HTML:

```
<div class="form">
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="100" checked="checked" />100
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="200" />200
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="300" />300
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="other" />other
</div>


<input type="radio" name="img" value="100"/> img1
<input type="radio" name="img" value="200"/> img2
<input type="radio" name="img" value="100"/> img3
<input type="radio" name="img" value="200"/> img4
<input type="radio" name="img" value="300"/> img5
<input type="radio" name="img" value="100"/> img6
<input type="radio" name="img" value="200"/> img7
<input type="radio" name="img" value="300"/> img8
<input type="radio" name="img" value="200"/> img9
<input type="radio" name="img" value="100"/> img10
```

What i'm trying to achieve is jQuery show or hide of bottom radio buttons matching values of top radio buttons, i.e. if a user clicks on top radio button then the list will displayed based on the value of that button user checked. I found many similiar answers but all were based on either classes or `div`s. None told about matching values. So I had to post this.

I've also created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpLYV/) with this code.

Comment: `$('input[type="radio"][value="..."]')`?

Comment: @David http://jsfiddle.net/fpLYV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it similar to the below but note that the text for each radio button like `img1, img2, etc` won't hide as they are not inside an element which can be selected along with the radio button.

```
var imageRadioButtons = $('[name="img"]');

$('[name="type"]').click(function(){
    var selectedValue = this.value;
    imageRadioButtons.show();

    imageRadioButtons.filter(function(){
        return this.value === selectedValue;
    }).hide();
})
```

---

[**DEMO 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/ZwLyf/) - Hide matching radio buttons

---

**Edit**

> so if they are to be hide then each shall be inside one div id
>   element? or div class element?

You can for example wrap them into a span like this:

```
<div class="form">
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="100" checked="checked" />100
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="200" />200
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="300" />300
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="other" />other
</div>


<input type="radio" name="img" value="100"/> <span>img1</span>
<input type="radio" name="img" value="200"/> <span>img2</span>
<input type="radio" name="img" value="100"/> <span>img3</span>
<input type="radio" name="img" value="200"/> <span>img4</span>
<input type="radio" name="img" value="300"/> <span>img5</span>
<input type="radio" name="img" value="100"/> <span>img6</span>
<input type="radio" name="img" value="200"/> <span>img7</span>
<input type="radio" name="img" value="300"/> <span>img8</span>
<input type="radio" name="img" value="200"/> <span>img9</span>
<input type="radio" name="img" value="100"/> <span>img10</span>
```

Then you can adjust the script to always hide the next span element following the current input along with it, similar to this:

```
imageRadioButtons.filter(function(){
    return this.value === selectedValue;
}).hide().next('span').hide();
```

---

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/4yGy3/) - Hide matching radio buttons and text

---

In addition I updated the script for DEMO 2 to also hide the matching buttons when initially loaded. You can adjust anything else you need from there.

Full script from DEMO 2:

```
var typeRadioButtons = $('[name="type"]');
var imageRadioButtons = $('[name="img"]');

var hideSelected = function(selectedValue){
    imageRadioButtons.filter(function(){
        return this.value === selectedValue;
    }).hide().next('span').hide();
};

var initValue = typeRadioButtons.filter(function(){
    return this.checked;
})[0].value;

hideSelected(initValue);

typeRadioButtons.click(function(){
    var selectedValue = this.value;
    imageRadioButtons.show().next('span').show();

    hideSelected(selectedValue);
});
```

Comment: so if they are to be hide then each shall be inside one div id element? or div class element?

Comment: @user2057047: I edited my answer to include an example one way you can deal with the text. wrap it into a span and hide/show the radio buttons and the span following the current element. I included a demo and also updated the code to wrap the hid-code into a function so you can call it when the page loads too and when needed on the click events. That should be enough to get you started hopefully.